# The email address is badly formatted - Firebase Reauthentication

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi guys I have a problem with reauthentication. I'm providing an email from currentUser state and password from popup window.

This is how reauth function looks now:

```
async function reauthenticate(password: string) {
    try {
      if (currentUser) {
        console.log(currentUser?.email);
        const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
          currentUser.email!,
          password,
        );
        console.log(credential);
        await currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
        return true;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      throw 'Please try again';
    }
  }
```

And this is output from the console. I have no idea why I have a "The email address is badly formatted" error. The provided email doesn't have white spaces.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: From the order of your console comments it looks like `console.log(currentUser?.email);` is giving the output `Pilot9392!`, are you sure you don't have the username/password fields backwards?

Comment: No, the first log is from popout and it's password.